# What is the best workaround to store a predefined list items of items inside a single column in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm working on a project for storing medical records of patients in an hospital booking system, and I'm stuck on the allergy column. Each patient might have or might not have one or more allergies. The type of data in that regard is 'predefined' hence there're certainly a lot types of allergies but the number is ultimately finite.

I'm well aware that there aren't ways to store a sequence of items in a single column: relational databases by nature store one value per row/column combination but I've seen a few workarounds, and I'd like to ask about what is the best approach.

I can't use a `Set` datatype since there are certainly more than 64 allergies.

I could create another table altogether for the allergies with the following columns:
`allergy(patient_id,seq_no,allergies)`, where the primary key is a combination of the first two column.

While this approach would allow me to query on a specific patient
`select allergies from allergy where id = patient_id;` I don't know how to reset the auto increment value for the `seq_no` to 0 for each new patient.

I could store this type of data in a `JSON` data-type, but seems to me a very strange solution, I've never seen anyone using such datatype, I assume is quite infrequent.

Ultimately I can just store the data type inside a standard Varchar field but this will require extra work on the backend to retrieve the individual allergy, doesn't allow me to query through, and quite frankly is the less elegant solution.

Comment: That's a text book example of a [many-to-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relationship

Comment: FYI, Stack Overflow has a sibling site for database questions: http://DBA.StackExchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this type of a design you are going to be looking at three tables:

- allergy
- patient
- patientallergy

Fundamentally, the allergies information will have a different structure, even if a simple one, but it carries conceptually different information than the patient.

`allergy` might contain:

- allergyid (auto_inc)
- allergyname (varchar)

`patient` might contain:

- patient_id (auto_inc)
- patient_firstname (varchar)
- patient_lastname (varchar)

`patientallergy` would then just be the list of associated allergies-to-patient information:

- patient_id (int)
- allergy_id (int)

This would likely make sense as a Foreign Key relationship. The following would, for example, get the name of any allergies for a patient with the id of one:

```
Select allergy_name 
FROM `patientallergy` 
WHERE patient_id = 1 
LEFT JOIN allergy
```

The reason you would design this this way would be, as you correctly point out, the one-to-any relationship where a patient might have 0 or more allergies. Since the information is not something that *every* patient would have, you do not want to store it on the patient table (where all patients will have something like a name or date of birth). Since storing allergy information will otherwise have many empty rows for some patients and run rapidly out of space for others.

Essentially: your question strikes at what the heart of relational databases are designed to do. The power of them comes from being able to make a place to store something (`patients`, `allergies`) and then relate then (`patientsallergies`), since the relationship is structurally conveying different information than the things it relates.